How to prevent big sklearn random forest model from overloading the CPU core?
I trained a random forest model with sklearn using RandomizedSearchCV.
I stored the model as a joblib file and now I use it to make forecasts everyday on a server in a docker container.
Basically the process is:
watcher.py:
def watch():

    def run_script():
        scripts = ["forecaster.py"]
        for script in scripts:
            subprocess.run(['python', script], check=True)
        time.sleep(63)
    
    while True:
        now = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.utc).astimezone(berlin_tz)
        if now.hour == 23 and now.minute == 0:
            logging.info(f"Running scripts at {now}.")
            run_script()
        time.sleep(3) 
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.info("Watcher gestartet")
    watch()

forecaster.py:
data = get_data_from_API(...)
features = ["list", "of", "variables", "contained", "in", "data"]

rf = load(model_path.joblib)
rf_pred = rf.predict(data[features])

table = pd.DataFrame({
        'UTC': data['UTC'],
        'Forecast': rf_pred
        })
table.to_csv('somepath.csv')

However, I recently trained some better models that are a bigger size (>100.000KB, so not that big I think) and now my script keeps getting killed (<Signals.SIGKILL: 9>) and I can see in docker desktop that the CPU usage reaches 100% (the server's core has less capabilities than my laptop I trained the model on).
I tried models of different size. Smaller models work without problems, but larger models crash.
For the moment I stick to smaller models that are less accurate, which works, but I'm searching for a solution that works for any model I'd like to use.
I figured that probably parallel processing could be a solution, but I only find tutorials that either only work for other libraries like PyTorch or are about parallelizing while training the model, not while applying it.
How to resolve this?

Linux won't kill a process for using too much CPU. It will, however, kill a process for using too much memory. In that sense, making it run in parallel is likely to make the problem of your script getting killed worse, as parallel processing in Python typically takes more memory.

What's the docker environment on the computer where the script is getting killed? Is it one of the docker-inside-a-VM setups, like Docker Desktop for Windows, or is it Docker Engine? Are you using any of the memory limit features of Docker? Those act very similarly to getting OOM killed.

It's docker for Windows. Docker has 4 cores but I only use one of them. RAM isn't overloaded.

How much RAM is allocated to Docker?
